# How to Get Handle Types of a Process in C++

Tags: c++, performance, types, handle

i am writing a code which try to collect information about system-process performance. I have some counters like %Cpu, RAM, etc. but i am not able to get info about handles (like Process Explorer does).

To get handles count of a process we can use GetProcessHandleCount() but i need "something" that tells the global count of handles used in the computer and the type of those handles(File, Key, Event, Directory, etc)

Does anybody know if there is some function that get that information?

Thanks you!

Comment: Mark Russinovich knows how to read the undocumented kernel handle tables.  He's not sharing his secrets.